# how to install pip with yum on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip

I am use AWS with REL 7. the default EC2 mico instance has already install python.

but it encounter below error when i try to install pip by yum.

## sudo yum install pip

Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
No package pip available.
Error: Nothing to do

Anyone advise on how to install pip with yum?

Comment: the OS of EC2 is RHEL-7.3_HVM

Answer (score 49):

The following worked for me on Amazon Linux AMI 2:

`sudo yum -y install python-pip`

Comment: Note that to run it you have to say `python3 -m pip <args>`

Comment: also worked for me in Amazon Linux 2023

Answer (score 33):

To install pip3.6 in Amazon Linux., there is no python36-pip.
If you install python34-pip, it will also install python34 and point to it.

The best option that worked for me is the following:

```
#Download get-pip to current directory. It won't install anything, as of now
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

#Use python3.6 to install pip
python3 get-pip.py
#this will install pip3 and pip3.6
```

Based on your preference, if you like to install them for all users, you may choose to run it as 'sudo'

Comment: Worked like a charm.. in my case, Amazon linux has default Python version 2.7.14. Hence the second command was sudo python get-pip.py

Answer (score 17):

You can see what is available by executing

```
yum search pip
```

In my case I see

```
...
python2-pip.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python 2 packages
python3-pip.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python3 packages
```

So, you can install the version that you need. Since the default instance seems to have Python 2 installed, you probably want `python2-pip`. Thus:

```
sudo yum install python2-pip
```

and away you go.

Answer (score 8):

if you have already installed python you might want to install pip by:
sudo yum install python("version")-pip
for example:

```
sudo yum install python34-pip
```

Comment: still cannot find package...$ sudo yum install python34-pip
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7                       | 2.9 kB     00:00
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                         | 3.5 kB     00:00
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common                        | 3.8 kB     00:00
(1/2): rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64/upd | 1.9 MB   00:00
(2/2): rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64/pri |  38 MB   00:01
No package python34-pip available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: this the version what i used now:]$ sudo yum list python
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
Installed Packages
python.x86_64                     2.7.5-48.el7                     @anaconda/7.3

Comment: try different version of python. if you have python python-2.7.5. you need to install pip of that version.

Comment: cannot find I try to list and grep[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-241 ~]$ sudo yum list|grep python|grep pip
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-241 ~]$

Comment: sudo yum install python2-pip, or sudo yum install python3-pip, and so on

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways but this seems to be promising for me.

```
sudo yum install python3-pip
```

I prefer **searching any package name first** and then enter full name which I want to **install**.

```
yum search pip
```

this will give you results if any package with name `pip`.

Check if your installation is valid by `pip3 --version` which should print latest installed version on your system.

Answer (score 2):

Install python and then install pip

```
sudo yum install python34-pip
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well. I am using the AWS RHEL 7.5 image.

```
$ cat /etc/system-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
```

I enabled the `extras` and `optional` repos:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
```

But `sudo yum search pip` still did not show any relevant packages.

I downloaded the `pip` bootstrap installer and installed from there (see [Installing with get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py)):

```
sudo curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Note that many `pip` packages will require additional `yum` packages as well, e.g.:

- `gcc`
- `python-devel`

Answer (score 0):

The above answers seem to apply to python3 not python2
I'm running an instance where the default Python is 2.7

```
python --version
Python 2.7.14
```

I just tried to python-pip but it gave me pip for 2.6

To install pip for python 2.7 I installed the package pyton27-pip

```
sudo yum -y install python27-pip
```

That seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case is using docker with AmazonLinux2 image and python 2.7, I have to enable epel first : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

Then install by using `yum install python-pip` (because I'm using root user).